# Verificar intervalo entre duas datas

Tags: javascript

Preciso verificar se o intervalo entre duas datas não ultrapassa 12 meses, para isso fiz o seguinte em javascript:

```
var dataFinal = new Date();
var dataInicial = new Date();

dataFinal.setMonth($data.formInput.dataSelecionada.getMonth() +12);
dataInicial.setMonth($data.formInput.dataSelecionada.getMonth() -12);

var situacao = true;
if ($data.formInput.dataSelecionada02 >= dataFinal || $data.formInput.dataSelecionada02 <= dataInicial){
    situacao = false;
} else {
    situacao = true;
}

return (dataInicial+' | '+dataFinal);
```

Porém se eu seleciono a data `01/01/2017` inicialmente funciona normalmente, me é exibido `01/01/2016` e `01/01/2018` porém se eu mudo a data para `01/02/2016` ao invés das datas passarem a ser `01/02/2015` e `01/02/2017` me é retornado `01/02/2016` e `01/02/2018`, ou seja, o dia e o mês até alteram porém o ano não, como poderia resolver isso?

Comment: Existe uma biblioteca javascript chamada moment.js ela faz examtemnte o que vc esta querendo fazer https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @GuilhermeXavier, não recomende o uso da biblioteca `Moment.js.` essa biblioteca foi descontinuada e é mantida apenas para suprir projetos legados. Os próprios autores da biblioteca recomendam a [não utilização dessa biblioteca em novos projetos](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).

Answer (score 0):

Espero que isso possa ajudar:

```
var date1=new Date(2013,5,21);//Remember, months are 0 based in JS
var date2=new Date(2013,9,18);
var year1=date1.getFullYear();
var year2=date2.getFullYear();
var month1=date1.getMonth();
var month2=date2.getMonth();
if(month1===0){ //Have to take into account
  month1++;
  month2++;
}
var numberOfMonths;
```

1.Não considerando os meses month1 and month2:

```
numberOfMonths = (year2 - year1) * 12 + (month2 - month1) - 1;
```

2.Considerando apenas um dos meses:

```
numberOfMonths = (year2 - year1) * 12 + (month2 - month1);
```

3.Considerando ambos os meses:

```
numberOfMonths = (year2 - year1) * 12 + (month2 - month1) + 1;
```

Qualquer dúvida, segue o [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536379/difference-in-months-between-two-dates-in-javascript/15158873#15158873) para auxiliar

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o erro está na maneira como calcula a diferença entre datas. Um abordagem mais simples é a seguinte:

```js
var date1 = new Date(2018, 01, 01);
var date2 = new Date(2019, 02, 25);

var umDia = 1000*60*60*24;
var diasNoMes = 30;
var meses = Math.round((date2 - date1)/umDia/diasNoMes);

if (meses > 12){
  console.log("Superior a 12 meses!")
}
console.log(meses);
```

:)